# Finding original files in the Mac OS X installer

Tags: macos, install

I messed up my Apache config file, **httpd.conf**.

---

I followed this article, http://emresaglam.com/blog/1035, to try and find the original **httpd.conf** inside **Install OS X Mountain Lion.app**.

The article says that the Bom files ("Bill of Materials"), "describes what is in this pkg file and where they will be written to."

`Install OS X Mountain Lion.app -> Contents\SharedSupport\InstallESD.dmg -> Packages\***.pkg -> Bom`

However, the Bom files don't seem to be a complete listing. I extracted the contents of the **Payload** for **Essentials.pkg** and there was more to it then listed in its **Bom**.

---

Is there a better way to navigate and find the file I need from the installer, besides extracting the contents of each pkg file's Payload? Any tips or resources would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: I think maybe you are not findind the file because it is not in the distribution. I suspect that some other program builds it when needed. As evidence, I offer the fact that `pkgutil --files com.apple.pkg.Essentials | grep httpd.conf` does not print anything.

Comment: @harald-hanche-olsen Thank you! I'm so stupid for not looking to see what else `pkgutil` does. I found **httpd.conf** in BSD.pkg using `pkgutil --payload-files ... | grep httpd.conf`. If you post your comment as an answer, I'll mark it as answered, thanks! Also, I'm curious where I can find the file you refer to in your comment, `com.apple.pkg.Essentials`.

Comment: I posted a somewhat different answer, as I discovered more information. Sometimes, it seems that computers are *designed* to make us feel stupid …

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I first commented on your question, I was hindered by not having discovered httpd.conf on my own system. Now I have found it, however, and I can find out what packages owns it as follows:

```
; pkgutil --file-info /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf
volume: /
path: /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf

pkgid: com.apple.pkg.BSD
pkg-version: 10.8.0.1.1.1306847324
install-time: 1352382423
uid: 0
gid: 0
mode: 644
```

Note: `com.apple.pkg.BSD` is a *package name*, not a *filename*. You can find a list of all packages that `pkgutil` knows about by running

```
pkgutil --packages
```

Also note that running the above command on `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` does not yield a useful result, because `/etc` is a symbolic link to `/private/etc`.